# Why Picasso is resizing image in Android?

Tags: android, image, picasso

I'm loading images from a url using Picasso, but it automatically resizes my images. I'm using the following call:

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(imgView);
```

Whatever resizing the Picasso is doing is fine for me but because of this behavior I'm unable to decide the size of Placeholder image.

Original image size is w=185 & h=278 and same is my placeholder image.
How should I decide the placeholder image size?

Layout is as below:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_0" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2015-05-14"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think better is to fix size of `imgView` to 185x278.

Comment: Can you share the layout params of your `ImageView`?

Comment: My ImageView is inside a linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your picasso version to latest one.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

Picasso.get().load(galleryList[position].mediaUrl)
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder?.ivImags)
```